# if person A reserved a car, but person B buy the car, can person A take back the car? If so, what can person B do?

Tags: united-kingdom

The title explain basically everything.
What can person B can do if person A take back the car ?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "reserved"?

Comment: I've tried to cover the two basic scenarios, but the title ***doesn't explain everything*** and only *very barely* explains what is necessary for an answer at all. Please [edit] it to include more detail, this is a very poorly-written question.

Comment: Who is person A? What is reserving a car? Who did B pay to buy it? Why is A allowed to take it anywhere? Please make this make sense!

Answer (score 2):

The title doesn't explain everything. Here's a couple of scenarios.

### 1. No binding agreement to sell.

Let's say A goes to a car yard and talks to the dealer, and the A says "okay, can I reserve this car until next week?" The dealer says "Sure." They both walk away. **No money or any other promise changes hands.** Then at some point before A returns, B buys the car from the dealer.

In this case, A has no claim under contract law as an agreement to contract is not binding unless there consideration passes between the parties.

The car is completely and entirely B's.

### 2. A contract to contract

Let's say A goes to another car yard and talks to the dealer, and A remembers the car that he didn't get at that other car yard and says, "Okay, I'll pay you £1 for you to keep the offer to sell the car for £10,000 (it's a pretty nice car) open until next week. Agreed?" The car dealer says "Okay, sure." A pays him the £1 and they both walk away. Then at some point before A returns, B buys the car from the dealer.

In this case, A is able to file for breach of contract, because the car dealer agreed to keep the offer open and there was consideration, and so unlike the first scenario, A and the car dealer have a contractually binding agreement.

The possible remedies are specific performance or monetary damages - that is, a court may require the seller to complete the original agreement if it's possible, or else compensate A for the value of purchasing the car elsewhere, or else compensate A for the value of the purchase.

In this case, a court would take into account that B has purchased the car innocently and without knowledge of this bargain between A and the seller, and if the orders are for specific performance, some equitable compensation would also be available to B.

Answer (score -1):

If B has the car in his possession, and A takes the car away from B, that's plain and simple theft. B is the legitimate owner, and taking the car away from the legitimate owner without their permission is theft.

Obviously there's the possibility that your title that supposedly "explained everything" doesn't actually explain what you are planning to do at all. Don't assume that people can read your mind. Put into your question what you want to ask.

Comment: Half your response is commentary to the original asker, who hasn't returned since asking the question, nearly two years ago . Please put it in comments, not answers. If you don't believe the question is clear enough to answer, VTC.